# Problems with shadowbox in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jwplayer, shadowbox

I have a web page that plays several vídeos in a shadowbox: http://www.videospresentia.es

It works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. But I have a problem in IE: The vídeo only plays if the mouse is over the video window. Any Ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: That is bizarre. I would heavily recommend updating from V4 (which you are currently using) to at least V5, which can be downloaded here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-5.10

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion. I´ve changed the "player.swf" v4 to "Player.swf" v5. (I don´t know if that´s enough to be considered as a version update) The problem is still the same. :-(((

Comment: Hm, I see. Maybe there is something in ShadbowBox itself which is causing this? I have not used this particular lightbox before.

Comment: Do you recommend me any other lightbox able to play external .mp4 files?

Comment: I would try out FancyBox.

Comment: I´ve changed to Fancybox, and now the page runs with it. The problem has changed: Chrome and Safari work OK, but IE8, IE9 and Firefox freeze the video if you move the mouse pointer. This is Crazy... :-(

Comment: That is strange. I have used FancyBox myself and have been able to get it to work fine without this issue. Please contact me here and I will send you an example - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us